# Need to change loop to take into account the post category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to output from a custom post type called menu items but its not working for some reason can someone explain how I would change the below query to allow for the category correclty i am just getting empty results

```
  <?php
/*
 * Loop through Categories and Display Posts within
 */
$post_type = 'menu_items';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>



        <?php
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
                'tax_query' => array(
                 array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array ( 'salads-raw-things' ),
    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug,
                    )
                )

            );
        $posts = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>


                    <ul class="menu-list">
                        <li class="menu-item"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></p>
                            <p class="number">
                             <?php the_field('dish_number',$posts->ID); ?>

                 </li>





        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


    <?php endforeach;

endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop only to create the tax_query argument. Your query is overwrite each time the loop run.

You must do something like this :

```
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

// Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>
    <?php
            tax_query[]  = array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' =>$term                           
           );
endforeach ;
endforeach ;
```

Then, you can create you `$args` for only one `WP_Query`

```
   $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
            'tax_query' => array(
             array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array ( 'salads-raw-things' ),
),
     $tax_query
     )
   );

   $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Don't forget to properly set the relation you need between every taxonomies.

Hope it gives you some hints to make it works !

Comment: i only want to be able to post out all items under that category though of the cusotm post type

Comment: So, in $args remove 'tax_query' in my answer and replace it with 'tax_query'=>array($tax_query)